# Proving the divergence of a infinite integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

Could anyone give me some ideas/tips or solutions, how to get this task done? It's my homework in real analysis and I'm quite confused about it.

The task is as follows:

Let functions $f,g: [a,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be of such kind, that $f(x) \geq  0$ and $g(x) > 0$, when $x \in [a, \infty)$.
Let $\int_a^\infty f(x) dx$ be a divergent integral. Prove that at least one of the integrals

$$ \int_a^\infty f(x)g(x)dx, \qquad \int_a^\infty\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} dx$$

diverges.

Answer (score 3):

By Holder inequality
\begin{align*}
\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)dx&=\int_{a}^{\infty}\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)^{1/2}(f(x)g(x))^{1/2}dx\\
&\leq\left(\int_{a}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}dx\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)dx\right)^{1/2}\\
&<\infty,
\end{align*}
if the both integrals are convergent.

Comment: Probably the better proof as it doesn't require Lebesgue integration

Comment: A cheating proof is to use $ab\leq\dfrac{a^{2}}{2}+\dfrac{b^{2}}{2}$ and put $a$ to be the integral $(f(x)/g(x))^{1/2}$ with normalizing integral and similar to $b$, but that is essentially the proof of the special case of Holder's inequality to the $p=2$ case.

Answer (score 1):

If $a\ge0$ one can use elementary methods:

Assume that both $\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)dx$ and $\int_{a}^{\infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}dx$ converge.

then $$\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)+\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}dx$$ converge.

We can see that:

$$f(x)g(x)+\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\dfrac{f(x)g^{2}(x)+f(x)}{g(x)}=\dfrac{f(x)(g^{2}(x)+1)}{g(x)}=f(x)\cdot\dfrac{g^{2}(x)+1}{g(x)}$$

Therefore :

$$\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)+\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}dx=\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)\cdot\dfrac{g^{2}(x)+1}{g(x)}dx$$

Since $2\le\dfrac{x^{2}+1}{x}$ for every $x>0$ then $2f(x)<f(x)\cdot\dfrac{g^{2}(x)+1}{g(x)}$ for

every x>0 and by the monotonicity of the integral we get:

$$\int_{a}^{\infty}2f(x)dx\le\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)\cdot\dfrac{g^{2}(x)+1}{g(x)}dx$$

Then:

$$0\le\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)dx\le2\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)dx\le\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)+\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}dx$$

But $\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ diverges, which is a contradiction.

So atleast one of the integrals $\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)dx$ , $\int_{a}^{\infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}dx $ diverge.

Answer (score 0):

This is not completely rigorous but if you know Lebesgue integrals you can probably use this:
$$\infty=\int f(t)dt=\int_{\{x\in[a,\infty):g(x)>1\}}f(t)dt+\int_{\{x\in[a,\infty):g(x)\le1\}}f(t)dt$$

Now at least one of the two Integrals have to diverge for the sum to diverge, as f is a positive function. But if the first one converges, then:

$$\int f(t)g(t)dt\ge\int_{\{x\in[a,\infty):g(x)>1\}}f(t)g(t)dt\ge\int_{\{x\in[a,\infty):g(x)>1\}}f(t)\cdot 1dt=\infty$$

And if the second one diverges you do the same just with 1/g(x).